# Correct way of sending mail with name and email in FROM

Tags: php, email, jquery

I am having trouble getting this to work I want the email to send to me as:

```
 Persons Name <personsName@example.com>
```

I have been looking at other examples and I think I have everything right I can't find anything out of place in my code. The FROM in the email sent to me is FROM `username@just122.justhost.com` it is not showing up as either `Persons Name` or `personsName@example.com` unless I change the `$header` to

```
$header = 'From:' $email;
```

or

```
$header = 'From: $name;
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message']; 
    $subject = "Message from Blog"; 
    $header = 'From: ' . $name . '<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n"; 
    mail("test@example.com", $subject, $message, $header); 

?>
```

form

```
            <label for="name">Name:</label><input class="inputField" type="text" size="30" id="name"/><div style="display: none;" id="error-name"><font color="#FF0000">Your name here!</font></div><br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label><input class="inputField" type="text" size="30" id="email" /> <div style="display: none;" id="error-email"><font color="#FF0000">Your email here!</font></div><br />
            <div style="display: none;" id="error-message"><font color="#FF0000">Your message here!</font></div>
            <label for="message">Message:</label><textarea id="message" rows="9" cols="59"></textarea> <br />

            <input type="button" id="submit-button" value="Send Message" onclick="sendEmail();"/>
    <div id="messages">
                <div style="display: none;" id="loading"> <font color="#FF0000">Sending..</font></div> 
                <div style="display: none;" id="message-sent"><font color="#008040">Message sent!</font></div> 
                <div style="display: none;" id="error-content"><font color="#FF0000">Please enter some content!</font></div> 
    </div>
    <br />
    </div>
```

Ajax

```
function sendEmail() {
        $("#loading").fadeIn(100).show(); 
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val(); 
        var message = $("#message").val(); 
        var data = "name=" + name + "&email" + email + "&message=" + message; 


        if(name == "") { 
            $("#error-name").fadeIn(700).show(); 
            $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide(); 
        } else if(email == "") {
            $("#error-email").fadeIn(700).show();
            $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide(); 
        } else if(message == "") {
            $("#error-message").fadeIn(700).show();
            $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide(); 
        } else { 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "send.php", 
                data: data, 
                success: function() { 
                    $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide(); 
                    $('#message-sent').fadeIn(500).show(); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a small typo in the Javascript:

```
var data = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message;
```

Notice the `=` at the end of `&email=`

However, I do want to mention that most hosting providers don't allow you to send emails from domains that aren't on your server. Fortunately this problem turned out to be a typo.

Comment: Ok. Time for a number of follow-up questions. Do you have shell (SSH) access to the server? Is `example.com` being hosted on your server? Are you using shared hosting, a dedicated server, or a server that you set up yourself? @Yamaha32088

Comment: yea i have ssh access to it. the `test@example.com` is my email address except I obviously changed it for here. The `personsName@example.com` is not hosted I will use my gmail account or a made up email. It is shared hosting

Comment: Ok so I hardcoded the values in for the name email and message and it worked so now I am thinking there must be something wrong when it gets the REQUEST variables

Comment: I see. I know that some shared hosting providers won't allow you to send emails from domains that aren't hosted on the server. However, if you think it's a code error, I wish you luck in fixing it.

Comment: I forgot an '=' in the email `data` haha

Comment: Funny how that works. Glad your problem got solved. @Yamaha32088

Comment: if you update your answer I will accept it thanks for the help

Comment: `var data = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message;`